# Call jQuery UI Datepicker from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, struts

The following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ //this is the datepicker function
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

function jsFunction(){
   // i want to call the datepicker function from here
}
</script>
</head>
```

html

```
<html:image alt="Calendar" src="/images/icon_calendar.gif" 
    value="reset" onclick="jsFunction();" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

When I click on the text box, the text box will prompt a calendar to let me choose the date. This date picker is working fine.

I added in an image, and I want the text box to prompt the calendar when I click on the image instead of click on the text box. I would like to ask how to call the datepicker jquery from the onlick=jsFunction(); .

I an working in Java Struts2 framework.

Kindly advise/ help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to set an icon trigger (via API):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/images/icon_calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: Thanks. you save me. 
However, I have another question, the `/image/icon_calendar.gif` doesn't show correctly in my website if I follow your way. it is a broken image. It is working fine if I put in `<html:image>` . Is there any other configuration I need to do if put image in jquery function?

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me on another question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529078/call-javascript-function-in-strut-2

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [show method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show)

```
function jsFunction(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "show" );
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v5euX/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function jsFunction(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).focus();
}
```

or

```
function jsFunction(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    $(function() {

      $("#datepic").datepicker({ showOn: 'button',buttonImage: 'image/calendar.gif'});

    });

</script>

<input type="text" id="datepic" />
```